# JavaScript returning wrong height of an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to remember the height of an element once the page is loaded. I am using the jQuery "ready" function to set a callback for this:

```
var h_top;
var h_what;
var h_nav;

$(".people").ready(function() {
    h_top = $(".top").height();
    h_what = $(".what").height();
    h_nav = $(".nav").height();

    console.log("h_top: " + h_top.toString());
    console.log("h_what: " + h_what.toString());
    console.log("h_nav: " + h_nav.toString());
});
```

However, I am getting wrong values for all the elements. The returned values are always a few pixels different from the values that I get when calling the height functions from the browser console. I also tried outerHeight() and innerHeight(), but the results were the same.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE] illustrating the problem, in a runnable snippet?

Comment: Do you have images which load in those elements or maybe some other elements which need to be loaded before you check the height?

Comment: @ManuelCheța I don't have images, but I have an external font, and that was indeed the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery "ready" fires once the HTML has been fully parsed, but before all the external resources have loaded. You should be using the [`window.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event so that your code will execute after the images have finished downloading and their size is known.

From the [JQuery documentation on the `.ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> Browsers also provide the load event on the window object. When this
> event fires it indicates that all assets on the page have loaded,
> including images. This event can be watched in jQuery using `$( window ).on( "load", handler )`. **In cases where code relies on loaded assets
> (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code
> should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the onload handler to avoid getting values that do not match the final outcome of the browsers rendering process.

```
    $(window).load(function(){ ... }
```

For a detailed explanation of how parsing and rendering is working and to get a better understanding of why a single element being ready does not necessarily or put differently will more often than not match the final dimensions of the element, see this article: https://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/